# Show numbers with math results

Tags: c

I want to print user input numbers with math results
Like this
Addition of 2 + 8 = 10
But I am getting error
I am new in C/C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    /* Creating variables of math rules */
    int a, b, sum, sub, div, mult, rem;
    
    /* Getting user inputs using scanf*/
    printf("Enter the 1st number : ");  
    scanf("%d", &a);  
    printf("Enter the 2nd number : ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    
    /* Creating math calculations */
    sum = a + b;  
    sub = a - b;  
    mult = a * b;  
    div = a / b;  
    rem = a % b; 
    /* Printing the calculation results */
    printf("\nAddition of " a "+" b "=%d", sum);
    printf("\nSub = %d", sub);  
    printf("\nMult = %d", mult);  
    printf("\nDiv = %d", div);  
    printf("\nRem = %d \n", rem);  
  
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What error? There is no "C/C++" language, you should decide which one you are going with.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages - please pick only one, because the answers you get may be *very* different.

Comment: Using `conio.h` suggests that you are either using an ancient compiler or a very old book to learn from.

Comment: What @EugeneSh. said. Get a new book and/or compiler

Comment: `printf("\nAddition of " a "+" b "=%d", sum);` -> `printf("\nAddition of %d + %d =%d", a, b, sum);`

Comment: *"I am getting error"* - This is not very helpful. What error?

Answer (score 0):

This line is not valid syntax:

```
printf("\nAddition of " a "+" b "=%d", sum);
```

As you're placing string constants and variables adjacent to each other.

You're already using a format specifier for `sum`, so use two more for `a` and `b`:

```
printf("\nAddition of %d+%d=%d", a, b, sum);
```